# Unkown error when building matlab gui

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have creat a Matlab Gui which works perfectly but when I biuld it it runs until a certain point in my code(a function) and then produces the error sound. I have no idea why it stops at that particular function. I tried to change the function but still nothing happend. Is there a way to create a dialog that pops out when that error occurs?(already tried try/catch)

Comment: you can use `errordlg` to display an error to a user - but you need to specify the msg and where and when to display this error.  If you show the error message your getting then we may be able to help more...

Comment: The problem is that the error is not occuring when I run the .m main file of the gui. It is occuring after I run the compiled standalone application, so I cannot se an error message. I just hearing the error sound :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update comment gives info that this is a compiled GUI error question.

To resolve that run your exe from dos command window and you will see the error message written to the DOS prompt.  That way you can debug and resolve the issue.